# Command to change the wallpaper in XUbuntu

Tags: command-line, xfce, desktop-background

Doing a google search reveals the command

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path -s <image-path>
```

The first time I run this command I got a message saying that the property /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path does not exist in channel xfce4-desktop.

So, I created this property:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path -n -t string -s <image-path>
```

But still the background didn't change.

I then changed the background from space-03.jpg to space-04.jpg normally, from the Desktop Settings application of XUbuntu. Then I run:

```
$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop -lv
/backdrop/screen0/image-path                           /usr/share/backgrounds/space-03.jpg
/backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path                  /usr/share/backgrounds/space-03.jpg
/backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-show                  true
/backdrop/screen0/monitor1/image-path                  /usr/share/backgrounds/space-03.jpg
/backdrop/screen0/monitor1/image-show                  true
/backdrop/screen0/monitorLVDS1/workspace0/color-style  0
/backdrop/screen0/monitorLVDS1/workspace0/image-style  5
/backdrop/screen0/monitorLVDS1/workspace0/last-image   /usr/share/backgrounds/space-04.jpg
```

As you can see, the property `/backdrop/screen0/monitorLVDS1/workspace0/last-image` has changed (!).

If I change this property then it works just fine but the thing is that I need to find a general way in order to implement it in my program (Wallch).

Even `Variety` (which is a very nice program, by the way) does not work properly on my machine and chooses to change the property `/backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path` which does nothing.

One way would be to create all the possible properties and change all of them when needed, simultaneously. I don't like this solution because of 2 reasons:

1. Several system calls that will be needed
2. At one point I will need to take the current image's path (in order to open the folder of it, copy the path of it, delete it and some other functions that the program provides). I would not know which property holds the path of the truly set image in order to make it available to the program.

I also do not understand why XFCE has done it so complex. Why wouldn't one property be enough like in gsettings?

Comment: Have you tried this http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8198 or this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=838184

Comment: just tried it,
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path -s /usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-blue.jpg
works for me.... had never changed my background image before - take care to do it without root privileges because the settings are user specific.

Comment: @hakermania - maybe something like this script in #9 here - does this give you some ideas on how to proceed (or at least identify the correct monitor)? https://bugs.launchpad.net/variety/+bug/1064825

Comment: A similar question is here: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/380550/xubuntu-how-to-set-the-wallpaper-using-the-command-line](http://askubuntu.com/questions/380550/xubuntu-how-to-set-the-wallpaper-using-the-command-line)

Comment: @fossfreedom see the answer I gave in the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I think that should do the job

Use the following code to get the connected devices and count them:

```
connectedOutputs=$(xrandr | grep " connected" | sed -e "s/\([A-Z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/")
activeOutput=$(xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | sed -e "s/\([A-Z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/") 
connected=$(echo $connectedOutputs | wc -w)
```

then you have to manipulate over them and choose whether to set the value for image-path or last-image

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path -n -t string -s  ~/Pictures/1.jpeg
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitorLVDS1/workspace0/last-image -n -t string -s  ~/Pictures/1.jpeg

for i in $(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop -l|egrep -e "screen.*/monitor.*image-path$" -e "screen.*/monitor.*/last-image$"); do
    xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p $i -n -t string -s ~/Pictures/2.png  
    xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p $i -s ~/Pictures/2.png

done
```

Assume that 1.jpeg is any file just needed to create the string by default. And 2.png is the wanted picture to be set. I added the first line just to make sure that xfce4-desktop exists.

This script was tested in my machine and it is working well.

Hope that helps my friend

EDIT: A list of port names was found [here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2) like so:

> Output port names
>
> **Intel driver - UMS**
>
> VGA - Analog VGA output
>
> LVDS - Laptop panel
>
> DP1 - DisplayPort output
>
> TV - Integrated TV output
>
> TMDS-1 - First DVI SDVO output
>
> TMDS-2 - Second DVI SDVO output
>
> The SDVO and DVO TV outputs are not supported by the driver at this
>   time.
>
> **Intel driver - KMS**
>
> LVDS1 - Laptop panel
>
> VGA1 - Analog VGA output
>
> DVI1 - Digital video output
>
> **radeon driver**
>
> VGA-0 - Analog VGA output
>
> LVDS - Laptop panel
>
> S-video - Integrated TV output
>
> DVI-0 - DVI output

For further Info check [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config)

Comment: Why should that do the job?

Comment: @Seth Because I am looping through all available monitors and I will set the appropriate value for the found monitor. either last-image or image-path

Comment: In an newly installed XFCE system the values don't even exist. They are being created when you change once your desktop background manually. So, this isn't a good solution in my opinion. I include this answer in my question. I clearly say that I could try them all (create and change them every time), but this is far from being a good solution to the problem.

Comment: you can create properties like you did

Comment: @hakermania check the edit

Comment: @kamil So, if the properties do not yet exist (have to be created), will they be listed with `xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop -l` ?

Comment: @hakermania check again my friend

Comment: Again, this won't work in my case if I haven't changed my desktop background at least once. Because `/backdrop/screen0/monitorLVDS1/workspace0/last-image` will not exist (you only create `/backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path`). So, the solution is create them all and change them all, as I initially told. I will wait a bit and if nobody provides a better answer, you take the bounty ;)

Comment: @hakermania Actually there is a way to do it dynamically. Using xrandr gives you all monitors, but it needs some tweaking to grep only monitor names and then you can automate the process. I will update the answer again

Comment: The commands you posted both output `LVDS1`. They could output `0`, to my understanding. In the former case, the property should be `/backdrop/screen0/monitor$OUTPUT/workspace0/last-image`, while in the latter case, the property should be `/backdrop/screen0/monitor$OUTPUT/image-path`. Should I check each time the value of `$OUTPUT` and act correspondingly? How do I know that `$OUTPUT` cannot get a 3rd value, say `LVDS1monitor0` that needs the property `/backdrop/screen0/monitor$OUTPUT/workspace0/image-path`? (just an example). Sorry if I am being tiring, but the way needs to be really generic.

Comment: @hakermania You should manipulate xrandr, This is the only command that would help you as far as I know because we are working on xfce (based on X). xrandr is helpful but it isn't ready for displaying output as you need it. You have to use grep and sed to extract your needed parts from its output

Comment: I understand what you are saying. What I'm asking is this: The property changes between `LVDS1` and `0`. How do I know that there isn't any 3rd value, say `LVDS0` that needs another property?

Comment: @hakermania I assume that LVDSx start with LVDS1 but monitor starts with monitor0

Comment: Assumptions are bad for the stability of a program, though.